# How to get query params or input without trim in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, trim

I'm working on an endpoint that filters with input a list of resources.

For example, if my input is "key", it can retrieve:

```
keyboard
KeyBoard
red key
key of pc
```

but, if my input is "key " <- with white space, I have to use complete input, and not trim, and the result:

```
key of pc
```

So, the endpoint was made in Laravel, but when I try to get the query param or input, I get the data trimmed.

```php
    ...
    public function __invoke(CustomRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request->query('search')); // prints "key" and not "key "
        ...
    }
```

And CustomRequest is:

```php
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'search' => ['sometimes', 'nullable', 'string'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel uses `TrimStrings` middleware to trim the inputs. If you want to get untrimmed input you can whitelist the field name in the middleware

```php
//app/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings as Middleware;

class TrimStrings extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
        
        // Add the name of field for which input should not be trimmed here
        'search'
    ];
}
```